# Sets of subsets on $n$ objects

Tags: combinatorics

Given a number $n$, I want to have all the sets of subsets of $n$ elements in a way that adding all of them include all $n$ elements.

Let's say a set has 2 elements: $\{a,b\}$. For here we can have the set of subsets of ($\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$) and ($\{a,b\}$).

In a set of three elements $\{a,b,c\}$, I have all the sets of subsets ($\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}$) and ($\{a,b\},\{c\}$) and ($\{a\},\{b,c\}$) and ($\{a,c\},\{b\}$) and ($\{a,b,c\}$).

What kind of algorithm takes the number $n$ and gives me all the sets of these subsets.

P.S. I have to code this algorithm.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you, this is exactly what I have in mind. Is there any algorithm or method that I can use to get these Partitions in a program like c++?

Comment: Your examples suggest you are asking about generating [the partitions of a set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set), i.e. that the subsets not only cover the set but are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: I suggest a method for doing this that relies on recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The count of partitions of an $n$ element set is known as [the Bell number $B_n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_numbers), which satisfy an interesting recurrence relation.  However the Question is about generating the partitions rather than counting them.

The simplest algorithm is to generate various partitions of the first $n-1$ elements, and for each of these adjoin the $n$th element to each of those subsets in turn (thereby generating a partition of the entire $n$ element set).  **Added:** Of course the $n$th element might also be added as a singleton subset.

To start your recursion you might begin with zero elements, the empty set, for which there is only one solution (a singleton set containing the empty set).  Or you might prefer to begin with one element, a case that also has only one solution.